Decay of a particle with nonzero momentum into 2 particles: Why are there two solutions?
I am trying to solve a decay of a massive particle into 2 massless particles in the lab frame. I am not interested in the typical solution of boosting the system in the rest frame of the parent particle.
Let's suppose that we know the 4-momentum of the massive particle is $(E, \vec{p})$, and $p_{T1}$ and $p_{T2}$ are the momenta of the product particles. I want to compute the azimuthal angles $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ for both product particles.
To compute the azimuthal angles I used the following relations:
$$p_x = p_{T1} \cos\phi_1 + p_{T2} \cos\phi_2 \\ p_y = p_{T1}\sin\phi_1 + p_{T2} \sin\phi_2$$
where $p_x$ and $p_y$ are the momentum components of the parent particle.
I solved this system, but I don't understand why there are 2 possible solutions. The two solutions can be seen here.
There should be a reason why one of the solutions of this system is unphysical, but I don't know it.
I used a Python script to test both solutions. It is interesting that each solution is correct for different inputs.

It might help if you show more work and show your solutions.

In particle physics, a two-body decay refers to the decay of a single particle into two equal mass particles. It is confusing when you mention "parent particles" that implies more than one parent, which is a contradiction. If you really mean a single parent, then the velocities before and after will always be in a single plane and there is no need to present this problem as 3 dimensional which just overcomplicates the issue unnecessarily. As robphy already mentioned, you should show your two solutions if you want us to help you find out which one should be rejected.

I am assuming this is 3 dimensional because you mention pz, px and and py, but its not clear if you intended pz to be the magnitude of the momentum of the parent particle and px and py to be the magnitudes of the momentum of the two final particles, without implying a direction. If that is the case, something like p0, p1 and p2 would be clearer.

I hope it's clearer now.

Your question seems clearer now. Voted to reopen.

@NeutrinoVibes I have edited to make your notation clearer.
